# C# Fibonacci Sequence Replication

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I'm attempting to solve the second problem on Project Euler, here is the problem:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million.

So, I have set up the following:

```
using System;

namespace ProjectEuler
{
    class Question2
    {
        //Project Euler - Question 2
        //Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
        //1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
        //Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million
        static void Main()
        {
            int sum = 0;

            int oldNumber = 1;
            int currentNumber = 1;
            int nextNumber;

            while (currentNumber <= 500)
            {
                nextNumber = currentNumber + oldNumber;

                if (nextNumber % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sum += currentNumber;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Project Euler - Question 2\n\nAnswer: " + sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, there is nothing visible, just a cursor in the Windows command line.  I think that may be do the fact that currentNumber isn't getting updated, but I can't think of how to do that properly, if that even is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a condition to end your loop.  You never change the value of currentNumber to anything but 1.

You probably want something like:

```
nextNumber = currentNumber + oldNumber;
oldNumber = currentNumber;
currentNumber = nextNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the problem is because `currentNumber` is never updated. Look at the Fibonacci sequence again:

```
F(n+2) = F(n+1) + F(n)
         ^ currentNumber
^ nextNumber      ^ oldNumber
```

And in the next iteration:

```
F(n+3) = F(n+2) + F(n+1)
         ^ currentNumber
^ nextNumber      ^ oldNumber
```

Notice that the variables are shifted one position to the right and the oldest number is discarded. So you need to do something like this:

```
nextNumber = currentNumber + oldNumber;
oldNumber = currentNumber;
currentNumber = nextNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

namespace ProjectEuler
{
    class Question2
    {
        //Project Euler - Question 2
        //Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
        //1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
        //Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million
        static void Main()
        {
            int sum = 0;

            int currentNumber = 1;
        int lastNumber = 0;

            while (currentNumber <= 500)
            {
                if (currentNumber % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sum += currentNumber;
                }

        int nextNumber = lastNumber + currentNumber;
        lastNumber = currentNumber;
        currentNumber = nextNumber;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Project Euler - Question 2\n\nAnswer: " + sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sum = 0;
            foreach (var number in GetEvenFibonacciSeries())
            {
                if (sum + number > 4000000)
                    break;

                sum += number;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> GetEvenFibonacciSeries()
        {
            var first = 0;
            var second = 1;
            var next = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                next = first + second;
                first = second;
                second = next;
                if(next % 2 == 0)
                    yield return next;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't being updated, and you have an infinite loop.

An easier way to think of the Fibbonacci sequence, is that the next value is the sum of the previous two values.

Ie.

0 1.  Next is 1
Next is 2 (1+1)
Next is 3 (1+2)
Next is 5 (2+5)

So keep track of the last two values, and use that to create the next value.